# Past Simple or Past Perfect Continuous?

Tags: grammar, tenses, past-tense

If an action started in the past and lasted for some time, which tense should be used Past Simple or Past Perfect Continuous? For example, I worked out for two hours yesterday or I had been working out for two hours yesterday?

Comment: See also [ell.se]

Answer (score 1):

This depends on context. The most common occasions for speaking of your workout with the four past tense+aspect constructions are:

- If you are narrating past events in sequence, of which your workout was one, use the simple past.

  > I worked out for two hours yesterday, then went home and showered.
- If you are narrating past events and your workout was the temporal 'background' within which some event occurred, use the past progressive.

  > I was working out for two hours yesterday, during which my house was robbed.
- If you are narrating past events and 'cutting away' to mention your prior workout as the origin of some then-current state, use the past perfect.

  > I had worked out for two hours yesterday, and needed to go home and shower before I returned to the laboratory.
- If that prior workout continued right up to the time of which you are speaking, you may prefer to employ the past perfect progressive.

  > I had been working out for two hours yesterday when I was suddenly called to the telephone.